# AS3 inheritance & polymorphism

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, inheritance, air, polymorphism

let's say i create some custom version of DisplayObject that overrides some functions, setters and getters. Example:

```
public class MyDisplayObject extends DisplayObject{
    ....
    override public function get x():Number{
        return 123;
    }
    ....
}
```

and now I want to generate the class MyMovieClip, which is supposed to be the same as MovieClip, just with the difference that it inherits from MyDisplayObject instead of DisplayObject.
Is there any easy way to do that without having to recode the whole implementaiton of MovieClip (which is practically impossible)?

Comment: You are probably better off building your class via composition than inheritance. Sorry, not much of an answer, so I just put it in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

There is no actual multiple inheritance in ActionScript. But if you can live with reduced performance, you can extend the [`Proxy`](http://ltslashgt.com/2008/01/24/proxy-class-as3/) class to simulate it.

In your case, you'd create a class that extends `Proxy`, which holds an Object instance of any type, and you pass in the type via the constructor:   All calls to properties are forwarded to that instance, except for calls to `x`:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Proxy;
    import flash.utils.flash_proxy;


    public dynamic class MyMovieClip extends Proxy
    {
        private var mc:*;

        private function get differentX():Number {
            return 123;
        }

        private function set differentX( x:Number ):void {
            trace( "value received:"+x );
        }

        override flash_proxy function getProperty( name:* ):* {
            if(name == "x") return differentX;
            else return mc[name];
        }

        override flash_proxy function setProperty( name:*, value:* ):void {
            if(name == "x") differentX = value;
            else mc[name] = value;
        }

        public function MyMovieClip (clazz:Class = MovieClip) {
            if (clazz) mc = new clazz();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var mc : MyMovieClip = new MyMovieClip( Sprite );

mc.x = 1000;  // traces "value received:1000"
trace ("value returned:" + mc.x); // 123;
```

Obviously, though, this approach is limited to methods called on the Proxy - you can't add a Proxy to the display list, for example.

If you're willing to really get into this, you might also want to check out the [as3commons bytecode library](http://As3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/), which is allows you to manipulate the actual byte code used by AVM2 at runtime.  You can use it for [aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) by [generating dynamic proxies](http://As3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/proxy.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is a technique to fake multiple inheritance within ActionScript 3 as [outlined here](http://archive.darronschall.com/weblog/2006/10/multiple-inheritance-in-actionscript-3.html).  It basically involves importing an external AS file directly into another class. It's neither pretty or elegant but for all intents and purposes, it's a potential solution.

Of course, an interface cannot extend another class so you would need to take your custom code out of MyDisplayObject, place that in a separate interface (perhaps called MyInterface?) and then implement it into both **MyDisplayObject** (extending from DisplayObject) and **MyMovieClip** (extending from MovieClip) using the technique described on the website above.

Answer (score 1):

I propose you use a combination of composition and inheritance. In short:

1. Build your "extra" functionality in a parallel series of classes
2. Create your actual custom DisplayObject, MovieClip, etc. classes to **inherit** (IS-A) directly from the corresponding built-in Flash classes, but also HAVE-A (**composition**) instance of the corresponding exension class. To add or override the members in the custom class you just put a one-line wrapper to the extension class.

I'm sure an illustration would be more helpful, so here it is. Note that my extension classes inherit from each other (so I don't have to rewrite stuff that I want applied all down the chain), but the "useable" classes inherit from the Flash classes. Then it's pretty easy to copy and paste a few lines of wrapper code into each useable class:

```
// Base EXTENSION class. Doesn't inherit from anything
package {
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    public class DisplayObjectExtensions {
        private var _displayObject:DisplayObject;
        public function DisplayObjectExtensions(displayObject:DisplayObject){
            _displayObject = displayObject;
        }

        // Change the y property to be distance from bottom of stage
        public function get y():Number {
            return _displayObject.stage.stageHeight - _displayObject.y;
        }

        public function set y(value:Number):void {
            _displayObject.y = _displayObject.stage.stageHeight - value;
        }

        // A brand new property 
        private var _customProperty:String;
        public function get customProperty():String { return _customProperty; }
        public function set customProperty(value:String):void { _customProperty = value; }      
    }   
}

// MovieClip EXTENSION class. Inherits from base EXTENSION class:
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class MovieClipExtensions extends DisplayObjectExtensions {
        private var _movieClip:MovieClip;
        public function MovieClipExtensions(movieClip:MovieClip) {
            super(movieClip);
            _movieClip = movieClip;
        }
        // Adding custom logic to the gotoAndPlay method
        function gotoAndPlay(frame:Object, scene:String = null):void {
            trace("Skipping to frame " + frame + 
                  " in movie clip with customProperty = " + super.customProperty);
            _movieClip.gotoAndPlay(frame, scene);
        }
    }
}

// Useable DisplayObject class: Inherits from flash DisplayObject, has wrappers 
// for extended functionality contained in EXTENSION class.
package  {
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    public class MyDisplayObject extends DisplayObject {
        private var _extensions:DisplayObjectExtensions;
        public function MyDisplayObject() { 
            _extensions = new DisplayObjectExtensions(this);
        }
        public override function get y():Number { return _extensions.y; }
        public override function set y(value:Number) { _extensions.y = value; };
        public function get customProperty():String { return _extensions.customProperty; }
        public function set customProperty(value:String):void { _extensions.customProperty = value; }
    }
}

// Useable MovieClip class: Inherits from Flash MovieClip, only needs 
// to duplicate wrapper stubs to "inherit" all the custom extensions.
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class MyMovieClip extends MovieClip {
        private var _extensions:MovieClipExtensions;
        public function MyMovieClip() { 
            _extensions = new MovieClipExtensions(this);
        }

        // Copy and paste wrappers from MyDisplayObject
        public override function get y():Number { return _extensions.y; }
        public override function set y(value:Number) { _extensions.y = value; };
        public function get customProperty():String { return _extensions.customProperty; }
        public function set customProperty(value:String):void { _extensions.customProperty = value; }

        // Plus the MovieClip-specific override:
        public override function gotoAndPlay(frame:Object, scene:String = null):void {
            _extensions.gotoAndPlay(object, scene);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example with DisplayObject is too complex, because it involves dealing with some irregular things in AS3. DisplayObject is an abstract class, which you cannot extend in AS3 code, the closest you can get is Sprite.

With regard to extending, and, in particular, extending display objects, I hate to sound like a prick, but I would ask you this anyway: are you sure you really want it? There are a lot of troubles coming that way. By inheriting from a class that has over 100 methods you create a class, which is potentially too bloated, with the behavior you are unlikely to fully control or even comprehend. This is albeit common thing to do in AS3 (historically), is going to cost you dearly in terms of development and maintenance. Consider using composition, as has been noted before, or utility methods that specialize on some aspects or differences between your version of MovieClip and the built-in one.

However, in general, there may be yet another approach, which is quite similar to composition, yet not entirely the same. You can think about it as "decorator", but it's not precisely the same. The idea is that you have a class, which doesn't contain implementations of the methods, instead, it expects the implementations to be provided at run time. Consider the example below:

```
public class ClassWithDecorator
{

    public function ClassWithDecorator(decorator:Vector.<Function>)
    {
        super();
        this._decorator = decorator;
    }

    public function classMethod(integer:int, string:String):Boolean
    {
        return this._decorator[0].apply(this, [integer, string]);
    }

}
```

This will allow you to factor different sorts of similar objects by providing different sets of methods per class. This is somewhat less strict in terms of typing - because you "loose" the type of the function signature - you will, however, be notified at run time, if types don't match. Well, this is a tradeoff.

Another disadvantage - you will not be able to "sneak in" instances of this class in place, where some pre-defined types are required, even if you implement the required methods. Still, some times this is a viable solutions, if the number of different kinds of objects is possibly to big, or cannot be predicted at the time of writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Movieclip inherits from [DisplayObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html) 
So all you really have to do is extend MovieClip and you will inherit all the methods from the DisplayObject class.

I wold also suggest using Sprite instead of MovieClip if you are not using any frame methods.

```
MovieClip->Sprite->DisplayObjectContainer->InteractiveObject->DisplayObject->EventDispatcher->Object


public class MyDisplayObject extends MovieClip{
    ....
    override public function get x():Number{
        return 123;
    }
    ....
}
```